# SXA feature specific style option is missing for cloned rendering

Tags: sxa, presentation

Environment: Sitecore 9.0.2 + SXA 1.7.1

What i have done:
I cloned the default 'Navigation rendering' as 'Global Header'. I have added it to under 'Navigation' under available renderings.

Under 'rendering Variants', i created another 'variants' named 'Global header' and copied the variant from 'Navigation'.

What is happening:
For the new variant, i am not getting a particular (Navigation) subsection under style.

[image]

I am not being able to understand what is happening. Any input will be helpful.

Comment: did you assign that class to specific rendering i.e. `navigation` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow your cloned component in your custom style.

Go to your custom style (as example "Links Shown in Overlay" style on the screen below Styles > Common) and in "Allowed Renderings" field select your new component:

[image]

It is also mentioned in official SXA documentation:
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/add-a-style-for-a-rendering.html